# What is the purpose of `boolean` type in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, boolean

As it [said](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4) in `JVMS8`:

> Although the Java Virtual Machine defines a boolean type, it only provides
> very limited support for it. There are no Java Virtual Machine instructions solely
> dedicated to operations on boolean values. Instead, expressions in the Java
> programming language that operate on boolean values are compiled to use values
> of the Java Virtual Machine int data type.

Indeed, these two methods:

```
boolean expr1(boolean a, boolean b) {
    return a || b;
}

int expr2(int a, int b) {
    return ((a != 0) || (b != 0)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

will produce the same byte code (except the method signatures)

```
  boolean expr1(boolean, boolean);
    Signature: (ZZ)Z
    Code:
       0: iload_1       
       1: ifne          8
       4: iload_2       
       5: ifeq          12
       8: iconst_1      
       9: goto          13
      12: iconst_0      
      13: ireturn       

  int expr2(int, int);
    Signature: (II)I
    Code:
       0: iload_1       
       1: ifne          8
       4: iload_2       
       5: ifeq          12
       8: iconst_1      
       9: goto          13
      12: iconst_0      
      13: ireturn
```

So, I do not understand why `JVM` needs `boolean` type. Is it just for the runtime check of method signatures?

Comment: You can write much cleaner code with a `boolean` type than with an `int` that's emulating a `boolean`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Sure. But I'm talking not about `java` language itself, but about `JVM` which doesn't know about `java` language anything.

Comment: @sidgate The question is not about using `0/1` instead. The question is about, why does `JVM` need to declare special kind of type `boolean`, not just `int`, while it hasn't special instructions for `int`. So question not about `java` specs, but about `JVM` architecture.

Comment: This might be implementation specific. Even if the Oracle JVM implements `boolean`s as `int`s, not all JVM implementations have to. `int` and `boolean` are semantically different, so it may be useful for a JVM implementation to be aware of the difference and use this information e.g. for optimizations.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I can not agree with you. This is not about specific `Oracle` JVM implementation, but about `JVM` specs: there are not special boolean instructions in JVM, so it can not be `Oracle` specific

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As minimum it is needed to support methods overloading. Say, we have two methods in the same class

`boolean a(boolean x) {...}`

and

`boolean a(int x) {...}`

They can have different internal logic, so in the byte code they should be distinguished by their signatures.

Comment: The return type is part of the signature for the JVM as well.

Comment: As a simple practical example, `System.out.println(booleanVar);` does something different to `System.out.println(intVar);`